# select the min value of a id from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, min

I want to select the min value of a id from other table

here my table1

| id | grades |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |

my table2

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | andy |
| 2 | lucy |
| 3 | kevin |

I tried this

```
select table2.id, name, min(table1.grades) as grade from table1, table2
```

but it only shows 1 record

what I expected

| id | name | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | andy | 1 |
| 2 | lucy | 2 |
| 3 | kevin | 0(or null?) |

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, table2.name, MIN(table1.grades) grade
FROM table1
JOIN table2 USING (id)
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: You faster by 15 sec !

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I tried...

Comment: it shows nothing if there is id  "3" on table2 but has no grade on table1

Comment: @leo, use `left join`

Comment: @leo `.. FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 USING (id) ..`